# Is there a way to order MUI cards in react to fill the available space?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

It looks like this now:
[old](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zoYQI.png)

I want it to look like this:
[new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hidIY.png)

I use MUI grid:

```
<Grid container spacing={2}>
     <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
         <Box className="white-card">
             ....content...
         </Box>
     </Grid>
     <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
         <Box className="white-card">
             ....content...
         </Box>
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using MUI v5, you can use the `Masonry` component instead of `Grid`:

Straight out of the [doc](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-masonry/) example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import Masonry from '@mui/lab/Masonry';

const heights = [150, 30, 90, 70, 110, 150, 130, 80, 50, 90, 100, 150, 30, 50, 80];

const Item = styled(Paper)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: theme.palette.mode === 'dark' ? '#1A2027' : '#fff',
  ...theme.typography.body2,
  padding: theme.spacing(0.5),
  textAlign: 'center',
  color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
}));

export default function BasicMasonry() {
  return (
    <Box sx={{ width: 500, minHeight: 393 }}>
      <Masonry columns={4} spacing={2}>
        {heights.map((height, index) => (
          <Item key={index} sx={{ height }}>
            {index + 1}
          </Item>
        ))}
      </Masonry>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/itlq87?file=/demo.tsx:0-841)

Answer (score 0):

just add height 100% in your white-card class
here is a codesandbox example where i set the height and background color
https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-dirac-dfq0w4?file=/demo.js

Comment: Thats not really what I want, I may have phrased it wrong. I don't want the card to be  taller, I just want it to shift a bit more up. Like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8ZbH.png

Comment: you could checkout there lab documentation for masonry [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-masonry/)